# How to disable zip verification flag in stock recovery.img?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, twrp, selinux, systemless-root

In stock recovery there is an option to install zip from the sdcard but it doesn't allow installing zips with unknown signature. Twrp can install any zip without concerning about the the zip signature. So my question is simple i.e.

> What changes are required to stock recovery for disabling the signature validations provided a rooted adb shell in stock recovery and unlocked bootloader?

Any hex-patch for it or modifying any flag of prop.default file?

Comment: It's a more development related question. And after the change you want it would no more be a stock but custom recovery.

Comment: Do you mean kernel or stock recovery source code changes are required to achieve this?

Comment: If the device uses [Verifying Boot](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/verified-boot), modification of the recovery ROM would be of no use to you because afterwards it could not be booted anymore.

Comment: I have already removed avb checks from recovery.fstab + kernel sources.. Made a permissive kernel and it boots fine + giving me a permissive mode on system.

Comment: Also, I can modify system from stock recovery, I have tried to make MagiskManager a system app and it worked fine.

Comment: The problem is I was not able to understand how exactly Magisk install itself via flashing zip through twrp... So, I am just trying to disable the signature check and install it via stock recovery...

Comment: Magisk updater-script is written for TWRP only. AFAIK you can't install Magisk and TWRP same time in recovery ramdisk (from TWRP), unless you have TWRP built with special "install to ramdisk" option. Magisk does not official support Android 10 yet, it has issues

Comment: Understand that Magisk script will not work(because of Android 10 changes or might it will work after little modification like changing system mount point to /mnt/system which I can access on stock recovery adb shell..) but it should be possible to disable signature verification flash in stock recovery Right?